# What are some good options for playing a note written below the standard range of a double bass?

Tags: double-bass

I am currently playing a song for orchestra that requires me to play a d below the bass clef staff. Is there any reason why I should not just jump the note up an octave rather than tune the e string down? Are there other alternatives that I am not considering that do not require spending the money to buy a new bass.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a solo piece, a bass concerto, or part of an orchestra arrangement?

Comment: why not  build a 5 string bass or transpose the whole composition a whole tone higher?

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli Such schenanigans are often impractical for an *orchestral* setting, using an upright bass.

Comment: Please clarify: are you *writing* this song, or are you *playing* it in an orchestra?

Comment: I am playing it in orchestra I've edited for future clarity

Comment: Eat some bean burritos before the show, and deploy your afterburner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the standard 4 string double bass only goes down to E, and the cello down to C, this has been an issue for centuries.  Many 4 string basses these days have an extension device fitted to the E string which enables Eb, D, Db and C when needed.  This might be a cheaper option for you.  Also, plenty of 4 string players are quite happy to tune down to a D for a whole piece, as they are flexible in fingering those notes.
It is quite common for composers to jump up the octave when necessary if the line goes below the standard E (with the cellos continuing down).  You can lose something in doing that (depending on the shape of the passage) but it's not a big issue.

Comment: FWIW,  here's one bass store that will build-to-fit an extension  "starting at $1500"  https://uptonbass.com/?s=extension

Comment: Yes to both. Many players jump the octave and leave the low note for those who have an extension. Many existing basses can be fitted with an extension by a good luthier. It does cost quite a bit but much less than getting a new bass. BTW, we had Upton build a bass for our son. He is quite happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

A five string bass has been my answer for many years now - albeit an electric bass guitar. That won't help you as you don't want to spend lots of money, even for a string bass.

The option of de-tuning is not a bad one, but will jeopardise the rest of the piece as far as fingering is concerned.Were you using an electric bass guitar, then I'd recommend a 'Detuna', which with a flick, takes E down to D.

The option of playing that D note is a possibility, but it must fit in with the rest of the phrase(s). You can't really be playing a line of music downwards towards that D, only to jump nearly an octave when the D is required.

EDIT: another idea I've used on bass guitars - **but** would work on string basses is to move the strings *up*, so there is space where the lowest was for a heavier grade string, which gets tuned to B. So, B E A D. Obviously, this works until higher notes are required, but that's not in every piece.

EXTRA EDIT: there's always the 5ths tuning, which is an octave beow ceollo tuning, as in C G D A, so takes the lowest note down far enough, but needs practice to get used to different fingering. That's probably the best option!

Comment: Interesting but not really applicable to an acoustic orchestra.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - have you not come across 5 string double basses? That is an alternative - which is what OP asks about. Although there is cost involved. Tuning down is an obvious solution. Undoubtedly your dv?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft see the picture in Albrecht Hügli's answer.  Low C extensions do appear to be more common, but 5-string basses can certainly be seen in classical orchestras.  The problem with this solution is only that it is out of scope for the OP.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - the answer is now stil interesting, but also totally applicable to an acoustic orchetra...

Comment: @tim - ok, adjusted vote

Answer (score -2):

Just take a 5 strings double Bass:

It looks like this instrument already exists:

[image]

I don’t mean you have to buy another instrument. You might lease or rent one.

Or you could tune the E-string in D and put a movable bridge near the f-hole  (only for the D string of course) or single “fret” near the nut which you can keep there  (like a capo) when needing the E-tuned string and take away when you use the D ...

Comment: OP specifically says he doesn’t want to buy a new bass. Don’t think this is an answer.

Comment: you'd wonder what people all did and invented as the didn't have the money to buy something. Especially instruments.  Well, in this case I would try to fix a 5th string  that is tuned on a D on the 4-string Bass. Many instruments have been invented in a problem situation.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli adding a string is a major alteration that would cost a good deal of money.

Comment: The neck on a five string bass is wider. This is both for strength and to accomodate the extra string. There have been 5 string basses on a 4 string neck, but the spacing isn't good. And the bridge will need replacing. Then where does the tuning peg go?

Comment: @phoog  you cannot "just add" a string to an acoustic bowed instrument.  None of the mechanics will work.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft if you are a luthier (or, unlike OP, are willing to hire one) you can.  As Tim notes, it requires replacing the neck.

Comment: @Tim if you replace the neck you will replace it with one that has five tuning pegs.

Comment: @phoog - see my recent edit.

Comment: @ Carl: I would invent then such a thing that works ;)